# If today's date is between 2 different dates in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcode12

I would like to see if today's date is between 2 dates. And if today's date is between certain dates, it would change the value of a variable.

For example:

```
var p = 5

if viewModel.currentTime > "2021-04-23" && viewModel.currentTime < "2021-05-23"
{
    p = 2
}
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve but in the SwiftUI language but I don't know how to do it.

I was considering using an if statement but that doesn't work. I have this class that gets today's date.

```
    @Published var currentTime = ""
    
    var timer = Timer()
    
    init() {
        let repeatEveryXSeconds: TimeInterval = 1
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: repeatEveryXSeconds, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] timer in
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"
            self?.currentTime = formatter.string(from: Date())
        })
    }
}
struct Dates: View {
    
@StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
```

I wanted some help or suggestions on what I should do to complete this task.

Please let me know if there is any confusion. It is kind of difficult to explain.

UPDATE:

This is the error I am getting:

[image: Expected declaration]

Comment: You cannot run this code on the top level of a struct. Put it in a function or move it into the   timer class

Comment: I put it in a function and it worked, how can I return the value of p though?

Comment: Declare a return value in the function but it might be more useful to return only the result of the comparison

Comment: like this func 

pval() -> Int  {
    
       p = 1
    
    let now = Date()
    let day1 = Date.parse("2021-04-23")
    let day2 = Date.parse("2021-05-23")

    if now > day1 && now < day2 {
        p = 2
    }
       return p
    }

Comment: Yes, but I would do this `func pval() -> Bool {let now = Date() let day1 = Date.parse("2021-04-23") let day2 = Date.parse("2021-05-23") return now > day1 && now < day2  }` and somewhere else `p = pval() ? 2 : 1`

Comment: I was looking for something along the lines of this 

func pval() -> Int  {
    
       p = 1
    
    let now = Date()
    let day1 = Date.parse("2021-03-23")
    let day2 = Date.parse("2021-04-23")
    let day3 = Date.parse("2021-05-23")
    let day4 = Date.parse("2021-06-23")
        

    if now > day1 && now < day2 {
        p = 2
    }else if now > day2 && now < day3 {
        p = 3
    }else if now > day3 && now < day4 {
        p = 4
    }
        
       return p
    }
could I return the value of p and you it outside the func?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date`'s are `Comparable` so you can use < and > to compare your dates. The key is to perform all of your logic using `Date` types and then format the result. You can use the functions below to convert to and from `Date`'s and `String`'s.

```swift
public extension Date {

    static func parse(_ string: String, format: String = "yyyy-MM-dd") -> Date {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.default
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format

        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string)!
        return date
    }

    func dateString(_ format: String = "yyyy-MM-dd") -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

```swift
var p = 5
let now = Date()
let day1 = Date.parse("2021-04-23")
let day2 = Date.parse("2021-05-23")

if now > day1 && now < day2 {
    p = 2
}
print(p) // prints 2 as of May 1, 2021
```

Comment: that makes sense. do you know how to implement this an a if statement?

Comment: @CodeBeast Edited original answer with if statement example.

Comment: thank you so much, and would I put this before the var body or after? I am getting an error saying Expected declaration

Comment: @CodeBeast Not clear what you mean by 'var body'. I'm also not clear on why you're using a `Timer` in the code example. You can grab the current date/time by calling `Date()`, notice in the example above `let now = Date()`. Your view model would typically be responsible for formatting the `Date` into a user friendly representation (e.g. a String).

Comment: I used date before however, the date didn't update until I refreshed the app. so I used a timer instead so it could constantly update

Comment: I am trying what you suggested on a new file but its still giving me the error Expected declaration. I will update my post to show my results.

Comment: @CodeBeast you'll want to move that code so that it follows `var body: some View {` and before `TextView("\(p)")`.

Comment: I also tried that but its giving me more error. it says "Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231837/discussion-between-code-beast-and-norman).